# spring boot rest API got blocked

Tags: spring-boot, networking

I'm not very familiar with network configuration. I have an API server developed on spring boot with CORS enabled. The server works fine on the external network. But when I try to call API from the internal network, it got blocked, is there a way to resolve this problem in spring boot without changing network's configuration?

Comment: what does it mean by get blocked? Connection Refused? Or the request is pending and timeout?

Comment: @TianhaoWang It seems the api call cannot even send to the server. It got cut off in the middle.

Comment: It seems not like a spring-boot issue. Maybe it is because the incoming traffic ip is not in the whitelist if you are using a cloud service?